# Как переменную сделать видимой для 2-х форм и более?

Tags: delphi

Это делается через наследование?

Comment: А вызнаете, что вообще означает термин "наследование"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно описать переменную в разделе public, тогда она будет видна на всех формах, связанных с той, на которых вы ее описали

```
public
  MyVariant: integer;
```

основные разделы:
private - методы/свойства доступны только внутри класса
protected - методы/свойства доступны внутри класса и потомкам
public - все доступно всей программе :)

Так же можно передавать переменную в процедуры/функции

```
procedure TForm1.slowpoke(MyVariant: integer);
begin
   ...
end
```

другая форма

```
Procedure ...
var
 NewVariant: integer;
begin
   ...
   TForm1.slowpoke(NewVariant);
   ...
end;
```

Наследование позволяет создать свой класс со своими методами и свойствами, и вызывать их у детей.  
Так же в дельфи не строго прослеживается наследование, что позволяет разным классам, имеющим одного родителя, пользоваться методами друг друга.

Comment: Спасибо..это все недостаток опыта..студентик я))

Answer (score 3):

Один из эффективных способов организации глобальных переменных - создать отдельный Unit и в Interface-части объявить все необходимые переменные (и, естесственно, константы ежели таковые имеются). Если теперь в других модулях записать этот Unit в uses раздел, то все глобальные переменные можно использовать в рамках целого проекта (или проектов).